# Decoding JSON in dart

Tags: dart

I have this simple dart file which I'm running:

```
import 'dart:convert';

// ...

dynamic test() {
  final strJson = '{"ACB":["{\"date\":\"2020-02-28\",\"open\":1.36,\"close\":1.34,\"high\":1.4,\"low\":1.32,\"volume\":26469238}","{\"date\":\"2020-03-12\",\"open\":47.99,\"close\":45.54,\"high\":50.09,\"low\":45.37,\"volume\":50661745}"]}';
  final parsedJson = json.decode(strJson);
  print('${parsedJson.runtimeType} : $parsedJson');
}

main() {
  test();
}
```

But getting this weird exception:

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 12)
{"ACB":["{"date":"2020-02-28","open":1.36,"close":1.34,"high":1.4,"low":1.3...
           ^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1394:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:924:48)
#2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:31:10)
#3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:495:36)
#4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:153:41)
#5      test (file:///home/val/src/labs/maingain/test.dart:60:27)
#6      main (file:///home/val/src/labs/maingain/test.dart:65:3)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:307:19)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
```

I'll just say, that running similar code from the Flutter seems to work fine. Only when running this from command line give me the above.

Also validated JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `r` in front of the string literal.

The `'{"ACB":["{\"date\":....'` is a plain single-quoted Dart string literal. That means that backslash is a string escape, so `\"` only adds `"` to the string value. 
It's not a *necessary* escape because the string uses single quotes, but it's still treated like an escape.

That means that you pass the string content `{"ACB":["{"date":...` to the JSON decoder, which promptly gives up because the code is not valid JSON.

If you put an `r` in front of the string: `r'{"ACB":["{\"date\":...'` then the string literal becomes a *raw* string. That means that backslashes do not work as escapes, but are treated like literal characters. That makes the resulting string valid JSON.

Another alternative is to change every backslash to two: `'{"ACB":["{\\"date\\":...'`.

Comment: Subtleties of the language! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!